# Store basic variables on webpage for all viewers

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with storing basic variables across all viewers on a webpage. These variables can be changed and edited by any user, and are simple variables like a=1 and b=2. I do not need the variables to be real-time. From a few sources, I have heard that any variable on a 100% up-time web server is the same for all viewers. Is this correct? I'm sorry this might be a very basic question but I am very inexperienced :F

Comment: It sounds like you would need some type of storage software (ex: mongo, mysql, redis, memcacheD, mariaDB or even flat file), and then display it to the user with some type of back end code like `node.js`.

Comment: I agree. Looks like you want to use some Web Framework like Meteor, Django, Ruby on Rails or the like. Can you give us some more information about what you have tried so far?

Comment: My webhost has mySQL support, and I created a database, so mySQL seems to be the best way to go. I have no idea how to use it though.

Comment: (and phpmyadmin, whatever that is)

Comment: phpmyadmin is a web-based tool which is a GUI for managing your mySQL databases (creating tables, manipulating data, etc). Most web hosts use it, or something similar

Comment: if you've got mySQL, there's a very good chance your webhost also supports PHP, which is a programming language you can use to run queries on a mySQL database, and create web pages in a dynamic, data-driven fashion, which it sounds like you want, albeit in a fairly straightforward way to begin with (until you get the hang of it!)

Answer (score 0):

Like a few others have mentioned, you will have to use a database of some sort. Next you will have to get a web language that can access that data from the database such as PHP, ASP.NET, Node.js, etc. I would recommend PHP because of its popularity and the fact that many hosting sites support it. If you choose that path I can further assist you on how exactly you would go about doing that. If you have any other questions, do not hesitate to ask!

Comment: My webhost does support PHP. I do, though, not have any skill or prior knowledge of PHP.

Comment: Neither did I last summer, I can help you a bit by directing you to a few of the things that helped me. Trust me, once you learn it will be worth your time and effort. The first place I recommend is http://tutorialzine.com/2009/10/cool-login-system-php-jquery/

Comment: Download the file and them upload it to your host, from there tinker around. If you run into anything strange, ask because I may have already bumped into it.